# I have an excel sheet 1000 rows, if want the formula to copy down without changing for 4 rows , then change, copy down 4 rows , then change

Tags: excel

so the formula looks like this,

```
IF(Input!B3=",",Input!B3)
IF(Input!B3=",",Input!B3)
IF(Input!B3=",",Input!B3)
IF(Input!B3=",",Input!B3)
IF(input!B4=",",Input!B4)
IF(input!B4=",",Input!B4)
IF(input!B4=",",Input!B4)
IF(input!B4=",",Input!B4)
```

Is there a way to drag this down so that the row number increases only every 4 rows.?

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: Like a running count and divisible by 4?

Answer (score 3):

Use INDEX:

```
=IF(INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/4)+3)=",",INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/4)+3))
```

Comment: Scott, thanks for this. Someone I work with solved the problem. They used INDEX function similar to your code above. I just cant seem to understand how this code works. It would be much appreciated if you could send me a link to  a good source that could start my journey to understanding the excel index function.